# What permissions should I set the sitemap to?

Tags: html, xml, security, search, permissions

What permissions should I set on the **sitemap_index.xml** and **sitemap.xml** on my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the permissions in such a way that the web server can read the file when requested by an outside HTTP client.

The details of this will vary depending on your operating system and web server.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you generate them dynamically, I would put them to read-only for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress and the Google XML Sitemaps plugin, 666 permissions for sitemap.xml and sitemap.xml.gz files usually work.